# Custom read-host dialog for PowerShell 2 CTP3 ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

Is it possible to hook a custom dialog into the new PowerShell ISE (Integrated Scripting Environment) that replaces the existing .NET WinForms dialog. I am talking about the dialog that the `Read-Host` cmdlet launches to request for user input.

Answer (score 3):

For example, see this URL:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/pstips/feb08/pstip0208.mspx

1. Drop the full code into Notepad.
2. Add the first line:
   function read-host {
3. Add the last line:
   }
4. Copy all the contents from Notepad.
5. Paste it all into your PowerShell console.

Now, if you call read-host, you're going to see a new Windows Form.

Now, if I open other windows, it remains on top, but it seems it is not the top-most because I see it over everything else, but still need to click on it to make it active.

Answer (score 2):

What you CAN do is create a custom function that overrides Read-Host, so you're effectively usurping Read-Host and subbing your own functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can, no. You'd need to write your own hosting application. The ISE does have its own object model - I'm asking if what you're after is possible.